# How to use recompiled OpenCV build for Android

Tags: android, opencv, build, makefile

So I want to modify one of the files in the OpenCV build for Android and I followed the instructions on [their site](http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/wiki/Building_OpenCV4Android_from_trunk) to download the build and I was able to make it successfully. I modified one of the files (calibinit.cpp) and made it again and copied the files in the

> opencv/platforms/build_android_arm/lib/

folder into the jniLibs folder of my AndroidStudio Project.

However, the changes I made are definitely not working. I already had a previous OpenCV library linked to my project, so I'm pretty sure it's still using the old code. How do I use the new build with my AndroidStudio Project?

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide more details about how u use jni in Android Studio Project?

1. Did u try to clean and rebuild?
2. Do you have your own custom Android.mk? cause Android Studio will generate its own Android.mk, which can lead to unexpected result as u thought.

Comment: Yes, I did do a clean and rebuild.

I don't have an Android.mk file. I followed the instructions [here](http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/wiki/Building_OpenCV4Android_from_trunk) and for some reason the java files don't compile.

Answer (score 0):

1. delete jniLibs folder and every so file, you don't need them.
2. define NDK path in `local.properties` file:
   sdk.dir=D:\Android\SDK
   ndk.dir=D:\Android\NDK
3. create a folder(i named it jni) and put Android.mk and Application.mk in it (and an empty dummy.c file for preventing future buggy errors)
4. as Roy said, Android Studio generates it's own Android.mk, we have our own Android.mk file and Android Studio must use it.`jni.srcDirs = []`prevents that generation!
5. Extract openCV sources somewhere, i put them here: `D:\Android\Libs\OpenCV`
6. here is my files, modify and use them

***build.gradle:***

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "your.package"
    minSdkVersion 11
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        jni.srcDirs = [] /*disables automatic ndk-build call */
    }
}

task ndkBuild(type: Exec) {
    commandLine file('D:\\Android\\NDK\\ndk-build.cmd').absoluteFile,
            'NDK_PROJECT_PATH='+file('src\\main\\jni').absolutePath,
            'APP_BUILD_SCRIPT='+file('src\\main\\jni\\Android.mk').absolutePath,
            'NDK_APPLICATION_MK='+file('src\\main\\jni\\Application.mk').absolutePath,
            'NDK_LIBS_OUT='+file('src\\main\\jniLibs').absolutePath
}

    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn ndkBuild
    }


    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}



dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
    compile project(':openCVLibrary300rc1')
}
```

***Application.mk:***

```
APP_STL := gnustl_static
APP_CPPFLAGS := -frtti -fexceptions
APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a x86
APP_PLATFORM := android-8
```

***Android.mk:***

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

#opencv
OPENCVROOT:= D:/Android/Libs/OpenCV
OPENCV_CAMERA_MODULES:=on
OPENCV_INSTALL_MODULES:=on
OPENCV_LIB_TYPE:=SHARED
include ${OPENCVROOT}/sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk

//I have a local source file, you can remove it
LOCAL_SRC_FILES  := DetectionBasedTracker_jni.cpp

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)
LOCAL_LDLIBS += -llog
LOCAL_MODULE := detection_based_tracker
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```